# No overload for method 'IndexOf' takes 1 arguments. Worked under .NET framework but not .NET Core

Tags: c#, arrays, .net-core

I am migrating my code from an old .NET application to a new .NET Core console application. On one of the I have the following two lines:

```
int maxCount = separatorsCount.Max();
return maxCount == 0 ? '\0' : separators[separatorsCount.IndexOf(maxCount)];
```

`separators` is of type `IList<char>` and `separatorsCount` is of type `IList<int>`.

The error message is

> No overload for method 'IndexOf' takes 1 arguments

This is when the same code is working under the old .NET application.

Comment: exactly that framework(s) are you targeting? .NET Core is ambiguous... what version?

Comment: @MarcGravell framework is netcoreapp2.1. `separatorsCount` is an array containing the number of times a character occurs in file row and `maxCount` finds their maximum number.

Comment: that line shouldn't compile *anywhere* - you're using `maxCount` on the same line it is declared (over on the right); can you clarify what you changed in the edit?

Comment: @MarcGravell I am very sorry. Tried to simplify it which didn't go well. Take a look at the code again please.

Comment: Looks like a bug/tweak to overload resolution. Explicitly casting `separatorsCount` to `IList<int>` resolves it, otherwise it stubbornly sticks with the static `Array.IndexOf`.

Comment: Should be according to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.indexof?view=netcore-2.1#System_Array_IndexOf_System_Array_System_Object_)

Comment: I tried to get something that compiles in net472 as a starting point (so I can change it to netcoreapp2.1 to see it fail)... it refuses to compile there; can you show a minimal repro? here's my failed attempt, for example: https://gist.github.com/mgravell/2de3210ed7414067ad95e98919f8e148

Comment: @JeroenMostert you mean casting to `int[]`?

Comment: No, `separatorsCount` *is* an `int[]`. Casting it to that does nothing. `((IList<int>) separatorsCount).IndexOf(maxCount)` works for me. (Not that this ought to be necessary.) Don't ask me what .NET version I'm currently running, though... something recent, in LINQPad.

Comment: @JeroenMostert this gives me a "Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'char'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

Comment: Well, your code *is* incomplete and doesn't compile as-is -- consider making it compileable. Here's mine: `IList<char> separators = new char[] {}; int[] separatorsCount = new int[] {0}; int maxCount = separatorsCount.Max(); var x = maxCount == 0 ? '\0' : separators[((IList<int>)separatorsCount).IndexOf(maxCount)];` Without the `IList` cast, the call won't resolve. (I haste myself to say that I think it *should*, without the cast.) The `IList<T>` implementation of `int[]` is admittedly "magical", but still.

Comment: Since the return value of the function is `char`, I think I needed an extra casting. Now it is `(char)((IList<int>)separatorsCount).IndexOf(maxCount)` and the error is gone.

Comment: @JeroenMostert if you also get the same result you can post it as answer.

Comment: No, because it's far from an answer! An actual answer would explain if this is *supposed* to compile without the cast; if not, why not; if so, what's broken in recent compilers that doesn't make it work. AFAICT this ought to work as-is from .NET 2 and up, since both of these methods/interfaces were present there, and your observation that it used to work would reinforce that. I'm too lazy to extensively test across versions, though.

Comment: @JeroenMostert reasonable.

Comment: For what it's worth, with an `int[]`, this will not work with my .NET 2 compiler either -- it's not a bug. While `int[]` implements `IList<int>`, it only does so with explicit implementations, which is why calling `.IndexOf` directly will not work and will only have `Array.IndexOf` accessible. For the same reason `x.RemoveAt(0)` will not compile if `x` is `int[]`, which makes a bit more sense. An explicit cast to `IList<int>` (or an implicit conversion through assignment) is needed before it works with `int[]`.

Answer (score 3):

*Note to future readers:* The original question said that `separatorsCount` is of type `int[]`.

It's not lying to you :) There are no overloads of `Array.IndexOf()` that take 1 argument. Look at the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.indexof?view=netcore-2.1

But it is also a `static` method, so you have to use it like this:

```
Array.IndexOf(separatorsCount, maxCount)
```

I think you're used to [`List<T>.IndexOf()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.indexof?view=netcore-2.1), which is not static and takes 1 argument.

Comment: But has something happened regarding this from .NET Framework to Core?

Comment: No. Check the documentation. You can go back in versions on the top left of the page. It has always been a static method.

Comment: `Array.IndexOf()` does seem to be the only implementation of `IndexOf()` that is static. `List<T>.IndexOf()` and even `ArrayList.IndexOf()` are all instance methods taking 1 argument. So if this worked in your old code, verify the type that you were using it on.

Comment: The return value of the function was char and by using `(char)((IList<int>)separatorsCount).IndexOf(maxCount)` the error seems to be resolved.

Comment: @Disasterkid: that's obviously wrong -- the result should be used to index `separators`, not used as-is. The equivalent statement is `return maxCount == 0 ? '\0' : separators[((IList<int>) separatorsCount).IndexOf(maxCount)];`. (I'm not saying there's not a simpler alternative to this.)

Comment: @GabrielLuci I am slightly confused. You wrore I have to "use it like this" wheares the same code worked in the old work. Knowing apparently nothing has changed regarding this function, I am wondering what differs between these two versions.

Comment: Check your old code again and verify the exact type of `separatorsCount`.

Comment: @GabrielLuci it's `IList<int>`.

Comment: @GabrielLuci my bad. Sorry about that.

Comment: Well that's why it worked :) in this example you said it's `int[]`.

Comment: I know. My mistake. Would you like to edit the answer or should we leave it as is?

Comment: I see you changed your question to say it's an `IList<int>`, but if casting it to `IList<int>` made it suddenly work, then that means it wasn't an `IList<int>` to begin with.